# preact-cli project says “Can't resolve 'react'” when adding react-ga (aliasing issue)

Tags: preact

I have a Preact (`preact-cli`) project based on `preact create default`.

When adding `react-ga` (Google Analytics) I get this build error:

```
✖ ERROR ../node_modules/react-ga/dist/esm/components/OutboundLink.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react' in './node_modules/react-ga/dist/esm/components'
 @ ../node_modules/react-ga/dist/esm/components/OutboundLink.js 169:0-41 239:13-18 244:2-11
 @ ../node_modules/react-ga/dist/esm/index.js
 @ ./components/app.js
 @ ./index.js
 @ ../node_modules/preact-cli/lib/lib/entry.js
 @ multi ../node_modules/preact-cli/lib/lib/entry webpack-dev-server/client webpack/hot/dev-server
```

I’m using the default config (no custom `preact.config.js`) so output of `config.resolve.alias` is:

```
{
  style: 'MYPROJECT/src/style',
  'preact-cli-entrypoint': 'MYPROJECT/src/index',
  react: 'preact-compat',
  'react-dom': 'preact-compat',
  'react-addons-css-transition-group': 'preact-css-transition-group',
  'preact-cli/async-component': 'MYPROJECT/node_modules/@preact/async-loader/async.js'
}
```

Any tips?

**Update:** output of `npm ls | grep preact`:

```
├─┬ enzyme-adapter-preact-pure@2.2.0
│ └─┬ preact-render-to-string@4.1.0
├─┬ eslint-config-preact@1.1.0
├─┬ jest-preset-preact@1.0.0
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY preact@10.3.4
├─┬ preact-cli@3.0.0-rc.10
npm ERR!│ ├─┬ @preact/async-loader@3.0.0-rc.9
 peer dep missing: preact@^8.1.0, required by preact-render-spy@1.3.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@^15.6.2 || ^16.0, required by react-ga@2.7.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: webpack@4.28.4, required by babel-esm-plugin@0.7.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: preact@^8.1.0, required by @preact/async-loader@3.0.0-rc.9
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @types/react@^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0, required by react-hot-loader@4.12.20
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0, required by react-hot-loader@4.12.20
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react-dom@^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0, required by react-hot-loader@4.12.20
│ ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY preact@^8.1.0
├─┬ preact-helmet@4.0.0-alpha-3
│ └── preact-side-effect@1.3.0
├─┬ preact-render-spy@1.3.0
│ └─┬ preact-render-to-string@3.8.2
├─┬ preact-render-to-string@5.1.4
├── preact-router@3.2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using `preact-cli@2` and `preact@8` - there's an issue right now where Preact CLI v3 actually scaffolds Preact CLI v2 apps.

Update your project to Preact X and Preact CLI v3 by running the following:

```
npm i -D preact-cli@rc
npm i preact@latest preact-router@latest preact-render-to-string@latest
npm rm preact-compat
```

Comment: Thank you, will try that. Do you recommend _not_ installing `preact-cli` as global?

Comment: This upgrade changed:

`"preact-cli": "^3.0.0-rc.6" -> "^3.0.0-rc.10"`
and `"preact": "^10.3.2" -> "^10.3.4"`

...but the issue still remains.

Comment: global `preact-cli` is fine, it's just used for scaffolding new projects. the local version in a project is always given precedence.

Can you paste the result of `npm ls | grep preact`?